# Docx Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory with image

Tags: javascript, vue.js, docx

I am using the **Docx** lib on my application to generate a Word document.

Everything works except when I want to add an image

```
            new Paragraph({
              children: [
                new ImageRun({
                  data: fs.readFileSync('../../../../applications/components/src/assets/images/default-user.png').toString('base64'),
                  transformation: {
                    width: 100,
                    height: 100,
                  },
                }),
              ],
            }),
```

But I'm getting this error when it's the right way

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '../../../../applications/components/src/assets/images/default-user.png'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:458:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:360:35)
```

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Is applications directory in the root of the project? Have your tried `./applications/components/src/assets/images/default-user.png`?

Comment: @MikeW yes I try this but doesn't work